# Magento 2 : How to Fetch CMS Page Content Using Search

Tags: magento2, search, page, cms-pages, page-content

I want to fetch cms page content using Search.?

If anyone have any idea related to CMS Pages Content Search.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please refer the discussion under http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2891/how-to-add-other-pages-to-search-results-besides-just-products I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$queryText = $this->queryFactory->get()->getQueryText();

$pagesCollection=$objectManager->create('Magento\Cms\Model\Page')->getCollection()

                            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1)
                            ->addFieldToFilter(
                                            array('title','content'),
                                                array(
                                                    array('like'=>'%'.$queryText.'%'), 
                                                    array('like'=>'%'.$queryText.'%')
                                                )
                                            );
```

Comment: Have Any extension for it?

Comment: NO, above code use in controller

Comment: Can I create Any Block Or Model File?

Comment: any where you can use but just need to replace $queryText

Comment: So In my custom module,there are following folder etc,controller and view

Comment: controller of view any where you can you use just need to pass $queryText (text word which you need to search)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54487/discussion-between-nikhil-vaghela-and-moin-malek).

Comment: This works only for Mysql search engine, adapt the code for SolR or ElasticSearch

Comment: You Are Right @NikhilVaghela

Comment: Yes @FranckGarnier It is for Mysql Search engine

Comment: This code works, but you can also use fulltext query to improve results. Documentation : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: yes I am adding in it @FranckGarnier.I am adding three Features like All Words, Any Words,Exact Phrase. If you need it please tell me.

Comment: I do not need it, I use ElasticSearch, but update your post in order to share your results to the community

Comment: Can you please tell us guys where we need to add this code exactly.Sorry but there are so many learners which can be confused.?