# Magento 2 - To show CMS pages in catalog result pages

Tags: catalogsearch, cms-pages, search-result

How to show CMS pages in following format on catalog result pages.

On Catalog search result pages, i want to show second section in the form of CMS pages after product list or grid based on searched parameter query string.
I tried below codes.

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="CMS/Search/Block/Search" name="cmssearch.table" template="CMS_Search::search-cms.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

```
<?php
namespace CMS\Search\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

 protected  _resource;

class Search extends Template
{
public function __construct(Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource)
  {
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    parent::__construct($context);

  }

    public function getResultsofCMSPages()
    {
        $query = 'asdf';
        $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $tbl = $connection->getTableName('cms_page');
        $result = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT title,content,url FROM `'.$tbl.'` WHERE `is_active`=1' and `content` LIKE '%'.$query.'%' );
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Using couple of ref. as follows:
[Magento 2 : How to Fetch CMS Page Content Using Search](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162126/magento-2-how-to-fetch-cms-page-content-using-search)

At catalog search page, it should show as follows:

[image]